# Javascript: Having a 'var' keyword before the 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript

Philosophically, why can't I declare a new variable in JS by using this sort of code:

```
var this.blah = "hello"
```

I see that it hangs upon '*this*' being a variable that has a meaning already, but -exactly- how?

what about corner cases and constructor functions?

Comment: Because its not a variable, but a property which you are assigning to?

Comment: it's invalid for var names to have a dot. you can do var blah = this.blah = 'hello'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Comment: you can't modify/extend object definition

Answer (score 2):

When you assign properties of an object, you never need the `var` keyword. That is, you should never have something like `var obj.prop = ...`.

Comment: what about the window object as an un-named global? ;P